# Select option from a dropdown menu using Rselenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I am really new to RSelenium, so I am sorry if the question below looks simple.

I am trying to download some international trade data from https://comtrade.un.org/Data/

When I write "Rep. of Korea", a dropdown menu appears with two options, i.e.

- Dem. People's Rep. of Korea
- Rep. of Korea

The benchmark option is "Dem. People's Rep. of Korea" in this case.

How do I force RSelenium to select the correct option here ("Rep. of Korea")?

I have tried several ways to select this, but with no success

```
find3<-find2$findElement(using = 'id', 'select2-drop')
find3$sendKeysToElement(list('Rep. of Korea'))

find4<-find2$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//*select[@class = 'select2-drop']/option[@value = 'Rep. of Korea']")
```

Comment: If it's a dropdown, you should be able to click the dropdown menu (I'm guessing "select2-drop"), then click the option you want. You can get the option based on its text or some other attribute.

Comment: Hi camille, thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to make this selection automatic, i.e. let the code to choose the correct option for me. In other websites I can do it easility with  `find2$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//*select[@class = 'select2-drop']/option[@value = 'Rep. of Korea']")` but not on this one

Comment: Try first clicking the element and then use `sendKeysToElement`